# Issue while opening an IE object with vbscript

Tags: internet-explorer, object, vbscript, sleep

I am populating a form with VBscript. Now, if the user is not logged in i am waiting till he logs in, then i am populating the form. Here is the code

```
    While ie.document.getElementById("age") Is Nothing

    Wend
```

The idea is till the script can find the "age" element it will be running in a loop. Once, he logs in succefully, he will be redirected to form where the script can finds the "age" element and exits the loop. Then the below code fills the form

```
    IE.Document.All.Item("sample").Value = "sample"
```

Now, the issue is.. because of the while loop, when the user tries to enter the username and password, there is a lag in the input.. he has to type letter by letter slowly otherwise they are getting skipped. How i can solve this issue ?

Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried using [`WScript.Sleep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t81adfd(v=vs.84).aspx) in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it (from what I understand). If you want a better answer you should post your whole code.

```
Sub busy
do while ie.busy
wscript.sleep 200
loop
End Sub

On Error Resume Next
Call busy
Do until ie.document.getElementById("age") = "age"
wscript.sleep 200
loop
Call busy
ie.Document.All.Item("sample").value = "sample"
```